# Change input text to select option with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have select option on one row in a table.
This is the html table

```
<td>
 <select id="itemClean" class="form-control" name="item">
    <option value="01">Certificate</option>
    <option value="02">Interior</option>
    <option value="03">Exterior</option>
    <option value="04">Foreign Marking</option>
 </select>
</td>

<td>
   <input id="remarks" class="form-control" type="text" name="remarks" placeholder="Describe it..">
</td>
```

My case, is, If select option that selected is Interior, I want to change the next column that have a text input `#remarks` to select option. How can I make it true. ?

This is my jquery code

```
/*Handling cleaning interior */
    $(document).on("change", "#itemClean", function () {
        var selected = $('#itemClean option:selected').text();
        var tr = $(this).closest("tr");
        var remarks = tr.find("#remarks").val();

        if (selected === "Interior") {
            var selRemarksCleaning = '<select class="form-control" name="remarksCleanig" id="remarksCleanig">';
            $.each(<?php echo json_encode($interior_cleaning_item); ?>, function (i, elem) {
                selRemarksCleaning += '<option value = ' + elem.NAMA_CLEAN_ITEM + '>' + elem.NAMA_CLEAN_ITEM + '</option>';
            });
            selRemarksCleaning += '</select>';

            //CHANGE THE INPUT TO THIS SELECT OPTION
        } else {

        }
    });
```

Any help it so appreciated.

**UPDATED** Thanks for the fast response to Mr.
This is the base code.

```
function addRowClean() {
    var selItem = '<select class="form-control" name ="item" id="itemClean">';

    $.each(<?php echo json_encode($cleaning_item); ?>, function (i, elem) {
        selItem += '<option value=' + elem.ITEM_ID + '>' + elem.NAMA_ITEM + '</option>';
    });

    selItem += '</select>';

    $("#tableClean").find('tbody').append('<tr><td>' +
            '<span class="label label-success btn-block" id="type">CLEANING</span></td><td>' + selItem +

       //BASED YOUR SUGGESTION
            '</td><td><input class="form-control remarks" type="text" name="remarks" placeholder="Describe it.." /><select class="form-control remarksCleanig" name="remarksCleanig"><option>1</option><option>2</option><option>3</option><option>4</option><option>5</option></select>' +

            '</td><td><button id="btnclean" class="btn btn-block btn-primary" type="button" data-toggle="toggle"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></button>' +

            '</td><td><button class="btn btn-block btn-danger" type="button"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></button>' +
            '</td></tr>');
    $(".time").inputmask("hh:mm");
}
```

The result is, both input and select option is show. Thanks again

Comment: what error do you have,what is the behavior you expect?

Comment: what is `selRepair `

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, given your JS code it would appear you have multiple elements with the same `id` attributes, which is invalid. Use classes to group multiple common elements.

Secondly, it would be much simpler to have both the `select` and the `input` in your HTML and simply `hide()`/`show()` the relevant one, based on the option chosen from the parent `select`. Try this:

```
<td>
    <select class="form-control itemClean" name="item">
        <option value="01">Certificate</option>
        <option value="02">Interior</option>
        <option value="03">Exterior</option>
        <option value="04">Foreign Marking</option>
    </select>
</td>

<td>
    <input class="form-control remarks" type="text" name="remarks" placeholder="Describe it.." />
    <select class="form-control remarksCleanig" name="remarksCleanig">
        <!-- populate this from your $interior_cleaning_item PHP variable... -->
    </select>
</td>
```

```css
.remarks {
    display: block;
}
.remarksCleanig {
    display: none;
}
```

```js
$(document).on("change", ".itemClean", function () {
    var selected = $(this).find'option:selected').text();
    var $tr = $(this).closest("tr");
    var remarks = $tr.find(".remarks").val();
    $tr.find('.remarks').toggle(selected != 'Interior');
    $tr.find('.remarksCleanig ').toggle(selected == 'Interior');
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/38bqy12j/)

Comment: Nice solution, but my row is dynamic, please see my update

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
    $(document).on("change",  'select[name="item"]', function () {
            var selected = $(this).find('option:selected').text();
            var tr = $(this).closest("tr");
            var remarks = tr.find("#remarks").val();

            if (selected === "Interior") {
                var selRemarksCleaning = '<select class="form-control" name="remarksCleanig" id="remarksCleanig">';
                $.each(<?php echo json_encode($interior_cleaning_item); ?>, function (i, elem) {
                    selRemarksCleaning += '<option value = ' + elem.NAMA_CLEAN_ITEM + '>' + elem.NAMA_CLEAN_ITEM + '</option>';
                });
                selRemarksCleaning += '</select>';

                tr.append($(selRemarksCleaning) );//add the select option
                tr.find("#remarks").hide();//hide the input field
            } else {
tr.find("#remarks").show();
                $('select[name="remarksCleanig"]').remove();
            }
        });
```

jsfiddle:https://jsfiddle.net/4oxbx7oz/1/